# After updating the version of UI5 in eclipse Luna 1.34.2 Smart Table not working

Tags: eclipse, sapui5

I have implemented the Smart Table in UI5 it was working fine upto the eclipse version of 1.32.

Now I have updated the UI5 version to 1.34, After update smart table is showing error.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Have you searched the relevant directory structure? One way of testing if you are missing resources locally is to use the CDN temporarily as the location for your resources. i.e. edit the location SAP resources are located (this may be in your index.html if you have one). i.e.: src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"

Comment: Except smart table every component is working fine.. I have checked this application in 1.32. that time it is working perfectly..